# How to use RetroFit2 to return any data in OnResponse

Tags: java, android, retrofit, retrofit2

I'm new with retrofit2 and I don't know how to return anything on the method `OnResponse`. 
I have these code:

```
  public boolean verificarUsuario (String login, String senha){

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BASE_URL).addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(g)).build();
    usuarioService service = retrofit.create(usuarioService.class);
    retrofit2.Call<Boolean> user = service.verificarUsuario(login,senha);
    user.enqueue(new Callback<Boolean>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Boolean> call, Response<Boolean> response) {
            boolean result = response.body();



        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Boolean> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
}
```

And I need to return the variable result when my method atualizarUsuario is called.

Here I have the interface of my method verificarUsuario:

```
@GET("get/usuarios/login/{login,senha}")
 Call<Boolean> verificarUsuario(@Path("login") String login, @Path("senha") String senha);
```

And here I have the Json of my method verificarUsuario:

```
   @GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/verificarUsuario/")
public String verificarUsuario(@QueryParam("login")String login, @QueryParam("senha") String senha) {

    usuarioDAO dao = new usuarioDAO();

    if(dao.verificarUsuario(login,senha)){
        return "true";
    }else{
        return "false";
    }
}
```

Does anybody know how to do it?

Comment: Please post the json that is being returned from your api call. You've set your response class as Boolean which can't be returned in a json

Comment: Have you ever checked [documentation](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) or [samples](https://github.com/square/retrofit/tree/master/samples/src/main/java/com/example/retrofit) available in Retrofit's repository?

Comment: @tommus Yes, but i dont understand how to return anything.

Comment: @KavachChandra i posted

Comment: @LucasCharles I'm taking about the json response data that you get after you call the api? Something like : {"key1":"value1", "key2":"value2"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Retrofit offers two types of calls, asynchronous calls and synchronous calls. Asynchronous calls are triggered by `enqueue`, which is the method you are calling, and let you pass in a `Callback` object to tell it what should happen when the call is done. If you want the calling method to wait for the response to come back and then return something based on that, you'll want to use the synchronous method instead, which is `execute`. However, you can't call `execute` on the UI thread in android, so if this is happening on the main thread, you'll need to make `verificarUsuario` return void, and then trigger whatever result you want in the callback you pass into `enqueue`

Comment: I understand but, how can i do these? Can you give a example of how can i trigger a result in the callback into enqueue? Please?

Comment: Is your code running in an activity? If it is then you can update a text view or dismiss a progress bar or start another activity, or something of that nature. The callback lets you run any android code, just whenever the response comes back